# How to change android showcaseview circle position?

Tags: android, showcaseview

I have created showcase view using https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView library. By default the showcase view circle is pointing to the center of the element. 
[image]

I want to move this circle to the beginning of the TextView

please help me

**Updates**

My layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bm.eg.activities.CreateProfileActivity">

     <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_transparent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_title"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/white_transparency_50"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

in activity

```
        mTVTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

        mShowcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)

                .setTarget(new ViewTarget(mTVTitle))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.sv_create_profile_title))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.sv_create_profile_title_description))
                .setStyle(R.style.CustomShowcaseTheme2)
                .blockAllTouches()
                .replaceEndButton(R.layout.showcase_view_cusom_button)

                .build();
```

Comment: how you are setting `.setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))?`

Comment: mTVTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);

.setTarget(new ViewTarget(mTVTitle ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after researching on your issue i found a solution for you.

You have to modify your `layout design` add one more `RelativeLayout` in your design like below and add **two** `TextViews` in it and include your `tv_title` and `hack_txt` textview in it like below.

**Note:** `hack_txt` android:hint="aaaaaa" must add 5 or 6 character in it and set `android:visibility="invisible"`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bm.eg.activities.CreateProfileActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar_transparent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/hint_title"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white_transparency_50"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hack_txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="aaaaaa"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>



        <!--... your other view-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now update here too

```
 mTVTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
 mTVHack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hack_txt);
```

Lastly Update here too.

```
.setTarget(new ViewTarget(mTVHack))
```

You are Done happy Coding.

[image]

Comment: not working same result, the circle is focusing center only

Comment: @BikeshMAnnur then add your layout and code in question.